# Why cant I download modules?

Tags: perl, cpan, perl-module

Hello guys am having a problem with downloading modules. Anytime i try to download a module , i get some weird messages. Its possible am doing something wrong because I haven't done it before, so its my first module.

The error message i get after running

```
cpan WWW::Mechanize
```

is

```
cpan WWW::MechanizeError while requiring CPAN::MyConfig:Can't find string terminator "]" anywhere before EOF at /Users/fayimora/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm line 5.
Compilation failed in require at /System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/CPAN/HandleConfig.pm line 478.}
```

Please how do i fix this so I can start downloading and using modules from CPAN. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you edited the file `/Users/fayimora/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm`? If so, you probably left out a `]` somewhere.

Comment: no.. i dnt even know what it looks like

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your CPAN configuration file (in `/Users/fayimora/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm`) is malformed. Fix it or remove it.

Comment: how do i remove it? An if i do how do i put the right one back

Comment: you can just rename it and CPAN will ask you a bunch of questions the next time it starts

Comment: yeah i dnt knw how to answer those questions :(